# Is there's a way to make android studio to compile error when a certain method isn't called no where in code?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

As the title says I want Android Studio to make a compile error or warning, whenever I implement an interface and the object that uses this interface isn't calling the interface methods.

For example:

Resources that can't be automatically released by the garbage collector needs to be `disposed()`. To avoid memory leak I want the IDEA to make an error or a warning when an object implements `Disposable`, and that object isn't calling `dispose()` method anywhere.

```
class Car implements Disposable{

    @MustBeCalled 
    void dispose(){
        ....
    }
}
```

```
class Main{
  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //No warning, since bmw.dispose() is called
        bmw = new Car(); 
    
        //a warning is displayed since camry.dispose() isn't called nowhere in the project
        camry = new Car(); 
    }

    public static void anotherMethod(){
        bmw.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: AS does gray out unused methods too. But what im looking for is a custom warning that warns you outside of the class, for each object created using that class. I want the warning to be displayed on the object, not inside the class. I thought maybe with Annotations, idk much about that though.

Comment: In general, no. You may find some standardized tooling support around the (Auto/)Closeable interface. Google's Error Prone has the concept of things that [must be closed](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MustBeClosedChecker), I don't know if that helps.

Comment: A bit like `finalize` or `AutoCloseable` with `try (Car car = new Car()) { ... }`. Both not working. Maybe something with a `WeakReference<Car>` if it is just dispose.

Comment: Ouch, that's a shame. I have a lib which I wrote years ago and sometimes I just don't remember that some classes require the object to be dispose manually.  Oh well... thanks guys.

Comment: @AndyTurner That sounds exactly what I'm looking for except for the try-with-resources part. My app uses a game-loop, where you create and dispose objects in seperate methods. My objects can and have to live a bit longer than a few lines of code. Usually, I dispose them once the user changes the screen.

Comment: You create a custom [Structural Search rule](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) to find such constructs and apply this [rule as the inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-work-with-structural-search-and-replace.html#custom_inspection).